# Can redisql run on Windows?

Tags: redis, redisql

Given that [redisql](https://github.com/RedBeardLab/rediSQL) requires "a modern version of Redis (> 5.0)" and that Redis for Windows is (as far as I know) either available for version 2. [here](https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads) or 3. [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases), is it impossible to run redisql on Windows at present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the release files of RediSQL, I don't see a Windows executable.
https://github.com/RedBeardLab/rediSQL/releases

So I assume that it is not readily runnable in Windows.

You could clarify by creating an issue here.
https://github.com/RedBeardLab/rediSQL

Answer (score 3):

here the RediSQL author.

If you need Windows executable please just ask for them!

I wasn't aware that somebody could need them, but now that I know I can prepare them as well!

Cheers,

Comment: I wasn't aware one could run Redis modules on Windows... (or Redis for that matter ;P)

Comment: I guessed behind WSL, that again I guessed, required some special compilation... Otherwise the question wouldn't make much sense...